# SKMaps: Turn LED for right/left turns

Tags: skmaps

I would like to know if it is possible to use SKMaps SDK to implement turn-by-turn navigation and switch the iPhone LED accordingly for right and left turns

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Take a look at this article about how to set the advice: http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/advisor-support-text-to-speech-scout-audio/